# Facebook Passport Strategy returning 500 error

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api, express, mongoose, passport-facebook

I am trying to make a **Logged in** or **Signed In** user to connect their account with facebook using passport.js facebook strategy, and save their `profile photo, id, gender, timeline cover and token` according the userSchema (as made in `user.js`model shown below.

I tried many combinations but still either getting `500`error from facebook, or if showing facebook auth, facebook can't return (the code combination, I tried) and save the object.

**PS** : *I had entered correct callback URL in facebook*

**PPS:** Please refer my UPDATED `routes.js` and updated `passport.js` below.

This is my `routes.js` file:

```
    app.get('/auth/connect/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook-connect', { authType: 'rerequest', scope: ['id', 'cover', 'gender', 'photos'] }));

app.get('/auth/connect/facebook/callback',
    passport.authenticate('facebook-connect', {
        successRedirect: '/profile/configure',
        failureRedirect: '/profile/congigure'
            // failureFlash: true
    }));
```

My `passport.js` file of facebook-connect:

```
passport.use('facebook-connect', new FacebookStrategy({
        clientID: configAuth.facebookAuth.clientID,
        clientSecret: configAuth.facebookAuth.clientSecret,
        callbackURL: configAuth.facebookAuth.callbackURL,
        profileFields: ['id', 'cover', 'gender', 'photos'],
        enableProof: true
    },
    function(token, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
        process.nextTick(function() {
            User.findOne({ 'local.facebook.id': profile.id }, function(err, user) {
                if (err)
                    return cb(err);

                if (user) {
                    return cb(null, false, req.flash('fbflash', 'This facebook user is already connected with an account at eBird.'));
                } else {

                    user.local.facebook.id = profile.id;
                    user.local.facebook.token = token;
                    user.local.profile.gender = profile.gender;
                    user.local.profile.herobg = profile.cover;
                    user.local.profile.dp = user.local.profile.dp ? user.local.profile.dp : profile.photos[0].value;
                    if (user.local.profile.dp == '') {
                        if (user.local.profile.gender == 'male') {
                            user.local.profile.dp = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/pinterested222/image/upload/v1487659283/an-av-3_jxrhwc.png';
                        }
                        if (user.local.profile.gender == 'female') {
                            user.local.profile.dp = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/pinterested222/image/upload/v1487770814/female-avatar_vvyvtj.png';
                        }
                    }

                    user.save(function(err) {
                        if (err)
                            throw err;
                        return cb(null, user);
                    });

                }
            });
        });
    }));
```

My `user.js` model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
var DateOnly = require('mongoose-dateonly')(mongoose);
var shortid = require('shortid');
var uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');

var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: {
        type: String,
        default: shortid.generate
    },
    local: {
        email: String,
        username: { type: String, unique: true },
        firstname: String,
        surname: String,
        name: String,
        role: { type: String, default: 'user' },
        department: String,
        pno: Number,
        password: String,
        verified: { type: Boolean, default: false },
        profile: {
            dp: String,
            createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
            herobg: String,
            location: String,
            website: String,
            gender: String,
            birthday: DateOnly,
            lastlogin: { type: Date },
            notifications: {
                name: String,
                namedp: String,
                type: { type: String },
                date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
                read: { type: Boolean, default: false }
            }
        },
        facebook: {
            id: String,
            token: String
        }
    }
});

userSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator, { message: '{Path}:{VALUE} is already taken.' });

userSchema.methods.generateHash = function(password) {
    return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8), null);
};

userSchema.methods.validPassword = function(password) {
    return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.local.password);
};

// userSchema.methods.bellTimesAgo = function(date);

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

The error, it's throwing me:

```
The www.facebook.com page isn’t working

www.facebook.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks.

---

**UPDATE - 1**

I [read](https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-linking-all-accounts-together) (& from [passportjs docs](http://passportjs.org/docs/authorize)) about `passport.authorize()` and updated my `passport.js` file accordig to passport.authorize() and also updated my routes, but still the same problem.

Here is my updated `passport.js`:

```
// Facebook Strategy Updated using authorize

passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
        clientID: configAuth.facebookAuth.clientID,
        clientSecret: configAuth.facebookAuth.clientSecret,
        callbackURL: configAuth.facebookAuth.callbackURL,
        // profileFields: ['id', 'cover', 'gender', 'photos'],
        // enableProof: true,
        passReqToCallback: true
    },
    function(req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        process.nextTick(function() {

            if (!req.user) {
                User.findOne({ 'local.facebook.id': profile.id }, function(err, user) {
                    if (err)
                        return done(err);

                    if (user) {
                        return done(null, false, req.flash('fbflash', 'This facebook user is already connected with an account at eBird.'));
                    } else {

                        user.local.facebook.id = profile.id;
                        user.local.facebook.token = accessToken;
                        user.local.profile.gender = profile.gender;
                        user.local.profile.herobg = profile.cover;
                        user.local.profile.dp = user.local.profile.dp ? user.local.profile.dp : profile.photos[0].value;
                        if (user.local.profile.dp == '') {
                            if (user.local.profile.gender == 'male') {
                                user.local.profile.dp = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/pinterested222/image/upload/v1487659283/an-av-3_jxrhwc.png';
                            }
                            if (user.local.profile.gender == 'female') {
                                user.local.profile.dp = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/pinterested222/image/upload/v1487770814/female-avatar_vvyvtj.png';
                            }
                        }

                        user.save(function(err) {
                            if (err)
                                throw err;
                            return done(null, user);
                        });

                    }
                });

            } else {
                var user = req.user;
                user.local.facebook.id = profile.id;
                user.local.facebook.token = accessToken;
                user.local.profile.gender = profile.gender;
                user.local.profile.herobg = profile.cover;
                user.local.profile.dp = user.local.profile.dp ? user.local.profile.dp : profile.photos[0].value;
                if (user.local.profile.dp == '') {
                    if (user.local.profile.gender == 'male') {
                        user.local.profile.dp = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/pinterested222/image/upload/v1487659283/an-av-3_jxrhwc.png';
                    }
                    if (user.local.profile.gender == 'female') {
                        user.local.profile.dp = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/pinterested222/image/upload/v1487770814/female-avatar_vvyvtj.png';
                    }
                }

                user.save(function(err) {
                    if (err)
                        throw err;
                    return done(null, user);
                });
            }
        });
    }));
```

Here is my updated `routes.js`:

```
app.get('/auth/connect/facebook', passport.authorize('facebook', { authType: 'rerequest', scope: ['id', 'cover', 'gender', 'photos'] }));

app.get('/auth/connect/facebook/callback',
    passport.authorize('facebook', {
        successRedirect: '/profile/configure',
        failureRedirect: '/profile/configure'
            // failureFlash: true
    })
);
```

**Here is the snapshot of my app callback settings from Facebook**:
[image]

**Snapshot of the error, facebook keeps throwing in:**
[image]

Comment: Is `facebook-connect` in `passport.authenticate` correct strategy? I can't find such in any documentation. If you use [passport-facebook](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook) there should be `passport.authenticate('facebook', ...)`

Comment: @AntonNovik I updated my settings and now using `passport.authorize('facebook')` and also updated my `passport.js` file, still no help.

Answer (score 4):

[Passport.js documentation](http://passportjs.org/docs/oauth) said:

> Values for the `scope` option are provider-specific. Consult the provider's documentation for details regarding supported scopes.

If you check allowed permissions in [Facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions), you will not find such permissions as `'id', 'cover', 'gender', 'photos'`. These items are part of a person's [public profile](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions?locale=en_US#reference-public_profile).

So, you should change `scope` in `routes.js` from:

`scope: ['id', 'cover', 'gender', 'photos']`

to:

`scope: ['public_profile']`

or don't specify scope, because `public_profile` is default facebook permission.

**P.S.** I told about your "update 1" code version.

Comment: Thanks! Removing the scope object worked calmly, I had added an answer for what worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Taking inspiration from @anton-novik, I fixed the bug.

The problem was in my `routes.js` file. First have a look at my `routes.js` file above, and then follow the code below:

```
app.get('/auth/connect/facebook', ensureLoggedIn('/login'), passport.authorize('facebook', { authType: 'rerequest' }));

app.get('/auth/connect/facebook/callback',
    passport.authenticate('facebook', {
        successRedirect: '/profile',
        failureRedirect: '/profile/settings',
        failureFlash: true
    })
);
```

There was no need of `scope` for the request I was making was already approved by Facebook for every app.

And then updated my `passport.js` file to look like this:

// // Facebook Strategy

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
        clientID: configAuth.facebookAuth.clientID,
        clientSecret: configAuth.facebookAuth.clientSecret,
        profileFields: ['id', 'picture.type(large)', 'gender', 'cover'],
        callbackURL: configAuth.facebookAuth.callbackURL,
        passReqToCallback: true
    },
    function(req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        process.nextTick(function() {
            // User is not logged in yet
            if (!req.user) {
                User.findOne({ 'local.facebook.id': profile.id }, function(err, user) {
                    if (err)
                        return done(err);
                    if (user) {
                        if (!user.facebook.token) {
                            user.facebook.token = accessToken;
                            user.facebook.name = profile.displayName;
                            user.facebook.email = profile.emails[0].value;
                            user.save(function(err) {
                                if (err) throw err;
                                return done(null, user);
                            });
                        }
                        return done(null, user);
                    } else {
                        // User should be created here
                        //  and saved to mongoose
                    }
                });
            }
            //else user is logged in and needs to be merged
            else {
                console.log(profile); //display the returned json from fb
                // Connect the user and save the details, since the user already exsists
                var user = req.user;
                user.local.facebook.id = profile.id;
                user.local.facebook.token = accessToken;
                user.local.profile.gender = profile.gender;
                user.local.profile.dp = profile.photos[0].value;
                user.local.profile.herobg = profile._json.cover.source;

                user.save(function(err) {
                    if (err)
                        throw err;
                    return done(null, user);
                });
            }
        });
    }));
```

Hope, it may help someone. :)